# The font is not connected locally

Tags: html, css, web, fonts, frontend

I downloaded the font to my computer Facon

This is how the connection works:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Facon';
  src: local('Facon'),
        url('../fonts/facon.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/facon.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

But this does not work like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Facon';
  src: local('Facon'),
        local('Facon-Bold-Italic'),
        url('../fonts/facon.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/facon.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

Facon has only bold and italic styles in one file
**Do I need to use the second line local() or not?**

Comment: Did you only download the font, or also install it in your system?

Comment: Also installed on the computer

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font_google.asp

This might help.

Do not install fonts & try to use google fonts

Comment: Google fonts are not a good idea for commercial projects

Comment: we installed fonts in our server itself for our website and that solved most of the problem

Comment: Try using it twice in separate way

Comment: Does not work)
Apparently you will have to abandon local ()